# How would you go about solving this graphical mass problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, newtonian-gravity, vectors

[image]

I've tried finding the x and y components of the vectors created by each mass to find the resulting vector's magnitude. However, my answer of 0.354 N keeps getting marked wrong. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Show us your workings...

Comment: All you need to do is calculate 2 vectors in rectangular coordinates and add them. There is some meticulous "bookkeeping" and the Pythagorean theorem and arithmetic. Your answer (0.354 meters) is a distance. That is not a force.

Comment: Hi Chris and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

[image]

By the use of coordinate geometry find the distance between the $2kg$ and other masses.  Now first of all use the expression for the gravitation force $F=Gm_1m_2/r^2$ between two particles. And by the use of principle of superposition tackle the particles pair by pair. By this I mean

Lets, assume the force between $4kg$ and $2kg$ is $\vec{F_1}$ and between $3.2kg$ and $2kg$ is $\vec{F_2}$ then, the net force would come out to be 
$$\vec{F_{net}}=\vec{F_1}+\vec{F_2}$$

Now after you get the magnitudes of force, use vector addition or just break the forces in $x$ and $y$ coordinate system and find the resultant. Hope it helps.